# Error on CreateReply when sending email with Outlook API

Tags: php, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, outlook-api

I'm using [deprecated now API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/beta/mail-rest-operations-beta#create-a-draft-reply-message) to send reply to existing email like this:

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/{message_id}/createreply
```

And getting error like this:

```
The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to (truncated...
```

Message ID is correct one, saved from just sent email.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

After lots of time spent to find the reason, it was the wrong Message ID at the end.

So, it looks like when you send email using draft, and you save that Message ID, it gets replaced eventually, once email is sent and moved to Sent folder. So, your Message ID is not valid anymore, and API returns 404 error.

The solution, is to save ConversationId from just created draft, and before sending Reply, get latest email using that ConversationId:

```
/me/messages?$select=Id&$top=100&$filter=conversationId eq 'AAQkADZlNzhlNj='
```